# How do I uninstall python from web platform installer?

Tags: python, web-platform-installer, microsoft-web-platform

I've installed python and some other packages using web platform installer, but I was having some issues getting a Django project to work so I uninstalled everything and am trying to get it going from scratch.  Web Platform Installer still shows that I have 'Windows Azure SDK for Python" and "Python 2.7 (32-bit)" installed however and I can't mark them as uninstalled.

I don't see where to uninstall from WPI at all, I uninstalled them using control panel.  I think I had originally installed python from the python site and had version 3.3 and 2.7 (64-bit), but now there are no entries containing 'python' when I try to uninstall a program from the control panel.

Does anyone know what is going on or can I download the setups from somewhere and try them manually?  Is there a way to reset what shows as installed in WPI?  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling WPI but that didn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok with a lot of fooling around I found this directory:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\PythonDetectInstalls
```

In a mangled sub-folder there is a powershell script `DetectPythonInistalls.ps1` that has these two lines for checking if python is installed already:

```
$regKey = "hklm:SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\$pythonVersion\InstallPath";
$correctRegKey = "hklm:SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\$pythonVersion\InstallPath";
```

Uninstalling all my pythons did not remove these keys.  After removing these registry keys with `regedit`, WPI allowed me to install its own version of python 2.7 and all the other goodies to go with the [Windows Azure Python SDK](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/) and it worked.